# Permission denied when running .exe in cmd on raspberry pi 3B+

Tags: raspbian, pi-3b+

I'm looking to run an exe file from the cmd of my raspberry pi but when I just put the path of the exe, I have :

```
Bash: MyPath.exe: Permission denied
```

I tried with sudo, but I have then:

```
sudo: MyPath.exe: command not found
```

Have you any idea to solve this please ?

Comment: Are you trying to run a Windows executable on Linux?

Comment: Yes, this is a c# executable. I can execute it by click but not with the cmd !

Comment: If the executable is in the current (working) directory, you must precede the name with ./   That is "./MyPath.exe" (without the quote marks).

Comment: `chmod 755 ./MyPath.exe` may be needed to get over the "permission denied".

Comment: It's ok, I found my answer (explain below) but I can't accept my own answer before 2 days...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ok, as it is a windows executable, I need to use the mono cmd:

```
sudo mono MyPath.exe
```

And it works! Of course, you need to install mono before on your raspberry:

```
sudo apt-get install mono-complete
```

Comment: Why do you think you need to run with `sudo`? Don't do that unless you absolutely have to.

Comment: I don't know, just to avoid permission denied, but why, can it be dangerous to use it everytime ?

Comment: Misuse of `sudo` means there's nothing to stop you destroying your system. You'll learn the hard way with `sudo rm -rf /` **Do not try that.**

Comment: Oh ! Okay thank you for the explanation, I'm just beggining with raspberrys, I'll try to avoid it !